# Boilerpipe python wrapper: ImportError: No module named extract

Tags: python, import, boilerpipe

I successfully installed JPype and Boilerpipe Python wrapper.

My JAVA_HOME path is correct (as far as I know).

I created a python file with the following code:

```
from boilerpipe.extract import Extractor

extractor = Extractor(extractor='ArticleExtractor', url='http://www.endalldisease.com/two-giant-underwater-crystal-pyramids-made-of-thick-glass-found-in-the-center-of-the-bermuda-triangle/')

extracted_text = extractor.getText()

print extracted_text
```

I am getting this error when I run `python boilerpipe.py`

```
ImportError: No module named extract
```

How can I solve this?

Thank you very much.

**EDIT**

Interestingly enough, I changed the name of the file from "boilerplate.py" to "test.py", and now the error is different:

```
ImportError: No module named boilerpipe
```

What could be causing this?

Could it be in the first case the file was trying to import from itself?

**Anyone know what might be causing a bad installation of Boilerpipe?**

Comment: Do you have a file or a folder called `boilerpipe` in the directory as `test.py`?

Comment: @Blender Actually I called the file boilerpipe.py

Comment: *Never* name your files with names already found in the library(the same is true for the name of variables and built-ins). Anyway, the last error shows that this `boilerplate` package is *not* installed or is not installed correctly.

Comment: @Bakuriu I ran sudo python setup.py install and it looks like everything was fine

Comment: Then `import boilerplate` shouldn't fail. Also: which `boilerplate` package is that?

Comment: @Bakuriu https://github.com/misja/python-boilerpipe